# Excel images to appear based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets on excel, one called Raw and one called Graphs. What I want to do is have some cells in Raw and it they =TRUE then I want a shape to appear on the Graphs page.

I am pretty new to VBA so i havent tried much :(

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    With Worksheets("Graph")
        If Me.Range("FK45").Value = True Then
            .Shapes("Test1").Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Me.Range("FK45").Value = False Then
            .Shapes("Test1").Visible = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I can get this to work so if FK45 is TRUE the image shows but if FK45 is FALSE it doesn't, But what I want to be able to do is add more to this e.g.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    With Worksheets("Graph")
        If Me.Range("FK45").Value = True Then
            .Shapes("Test1").Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Me.Range("FK45").Value = False Then
            .Shapes("Test1").Visible = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    With Worksheets("Graph")
        If Me.Range("FK46").Value = True Then
            .Shapes("Test2").Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Me.Range("FK46").Value = False Then
            .Shapes("Test2").Visible = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I want them all to be independent from each other and be able to add more if necessary

If FK45 is TRUE Image1 shows
If FK45 is FALSE Image1 doesn't show 
and/or 
If FK46 is TRUE Image2 shows
If FK46 is FALSE Image2 doesn't show 
and/or 
If FK47 is TRUE Image3 shows
If FK47 is FALSE Image3 doesn't show

and so on...

Comment: Perhaps you've meant *Worksheet.Change* event instead? Also, if you keep exiting sub after each cell check, you will not be able to check subsequent cells.

Answer (score 0):

### This is how I would do it

In VB Editor find your *Worksheet* and *Shape* objects and rename their system name to something intutive in their respective property windows.

[image: Worksheet object property window]

This way you can get rid of **`With Worksheets("Graph")`** construction, instead you can call them by their system name like **`With Graph`**. This will also come in handy if you wish to rename your worksheets or shapes.

Note that you **`Exit Sub`** after each cell check, your procedure stops after first cell and doesn't proceed any further.

Instead of *Worksheet.Calculate* event I advise using *Worksheet.Change*. This way you can iterate through your cells one by one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim shpImage As Shape

    For Each rngCell In Target.Cells
        ' check if change was made in "FK"
        If Not Intersect(rngCell, Me.Columns("FK")) Is Nothing Then
            Select Case rngCell.Row
                Case 45: Set shpImage = Graph.MyImage_1
                Case 46: Set shpImage = Graph.MyImage_2
            End Select
            ' if only boolean values present, no need for IF construction
            shpImage.Visible = rngCell.Value : Set shpImage = Nothing
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

If you had separate column for image name it would be much easier, you could check like this (for example, shape names are located in "FL" column)

```
Graph.Shapes(rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value).Visible = rngCell.Value
```